# Python 3 Importing Functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have imported functions before successfully, but the following has left me confused. Maybe, I just don't know enough about importing in python (I have tested the following principle on my own machine (Mac) and found that it works. I created fome functions with nothing but print statements and called them exactly the same way.).

I am running a script (train.py) that import functions from a file in the /src/models/models.py. Using `from  src.models.models import *` /src and train.py are in the same directory.

However, everytime I run `python train.py` I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'.

(source of the script [github](https://github.com/aildnont/covid-cxr/blob/master/src/train.py)) https://github.com/aildnont/covid-cxr/blob/master/src/train.py

Same directory hierarchy and syntax works on my own computer (again I used some simple functions with print statements). I am running train.py on a linux remote, using Python 3 on both machines. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: JFYI: It is not a good practice to use `import *`

Comment: Does your `src/` folder contain an `__init__.py` file?

Comment: @GrandPhuba Yes, there is a __init__.py in the /src directory.

Comment: How about the parent/current directory?

Comment: @GrandPhuba The /parent directory doesn't have the ```__init__.py``` file.

Comment: Can you try adding one and see if that fixes it?

Comment: @GrandPhuba I added an empty ```__init__.py``` in /parent, but didn't fix it. The parent directory was cloned from a git repo. I didn't modify anything other than adding the extra init.py

Comment: Share your code

Comment: @GrandPhuba Here is the code in it repo along with the /src. https://github.com/aildnont/covid-cxr/blob/master/src/train.py

Comment: Added an answer. I thought src/ and train.py were in the same directory but turns out train.py is inside src/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relative imports:

```
from models.models import *
```

Comment: I got "No module named '__main__.models' : '__main__' is not a package.

Comment: Try it without the trailing dot `from models.models import *`

Comment: That worked! Why didn't the absolute import work, but the relative import did? I would love to know if you have figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for and http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html